Outlook macro to run before email is being send
I have 3 QuickBooks files for 3 different companies, we are sending the sales orders and invoices from the same outlook application, I have 3 email accounts where I'm sending the emails from, each account is being used for a different company, I've developed a macro to detect which email account to use based on the subject, every time we create an email we hit the macro button to run it. is it possible to get the macro to run automatically when we hit the send button?

Sub Try()

    
    Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim MItem As MailItem
    Dim outaccount As Outlook.Account
    
    Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set MItem = myInspector.CurrentItem
    
    'Blanc Home
    If Right(MItem.Subject, 10) Like "Blanc Home" Then
        If Left(MItem.Subject, 3) Like "Sal" Then
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Orders @ Blanc Home"
        ElseIf Left(MItem.Subject, 3) Like "Inv" Then
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Billing @ Blanc Home"
        ElseIf Left(MItem.Subject, 3) Like "Sta" Then
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Billing @ Blanc Home"
        End If
        Set outaccount = Application.Session.Accounts.Item("Blanc Home")
        MItem.SendUsingAccount = outaccount
    Else
    End If
        
    'Distinctive Creations
    If Right(MItem.Subject, 9) Like "Creations" Then
        If Left(MItem.Subject, 3) Like "Sal" Then
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Orders @ Distinctive C"
        ElseIf Left(MItem.Subject, 3) Like "Inv" Then
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Billing @ Distinctive C"
        ElseIf Left(MItem.Subject, 3) Like "Sta" Then
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Billing @ Distinctive C"
        ElseIf Left(MItem.Subject, 5) Like "FW: I" Then
        MItem.Subject = Replace(MItem.Subject, "FW: ", "")
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Billing @ Distinctive C"
        ElseIf Left(MItem.Subject, 6) Like "FW: Sa" Then
        MItem.Subject = Replace(MItem.Subject, "FW: ", "")
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Orders @ Distinctive C"
        End If
        Set outaccount = Application.Session.Accounts.Item("DC Info")
        MItem.SendUsingAccount = outaccount
    Else
    End If
    
    'Fern Home
    If Right(MItem.Subject, 10) Like "Fern Home." Then
        If Left(MItem.Subject, 3) Like "Sal" Then
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Orders @ Fern Home"
        ElseIf Left(MItem.Subject, 3) Like "Inv" Then
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Billing @ Fern Home"
        ElseIf Left(MItem.Subject, 3) Like "Sta" Then
        MItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Billing @ Fern Home"
        End If
        MItem.Subject = Replace(MItem.Subject, "Home.", "Home")
        Set outaccount = Application.Session.Accounts.Item("Fern Home")
        MItem.SendUsingAccount = outaccount
    Else
    End If
    
End Sub


I think what you're looking for is the trigger that is the Send button, is that correct? I don't know what that is, but MS documentation may contain that. Another option is to create a new "Send" button that is the trigger for the macro and use that instead.

Oh, found another person asking this question with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569372/how-to-call-a-macro-on-send-button-click

Looks like you can get specific data you want in an email? The answer provided by the link above is worth a try.
